# Get pointer to matrix element in OpenCVSharp

Tags: c#, opencv, matrix

```
byte* stripePtr = &imagePixelStripe.At<byte>(n - 1, 0);
```

I am trying to create a pointer and get the error: cannot take the address of the given expression with imagePixelStripe being OpenCvSharp::Mat.

I need this pointer to access and modify elements in the matrix within c# script in unity.
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: use `Ptr`, not `At`, if you wanted a pointer

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need this pointer. Not for accessing, and neither for modifying elements in the matrix.

[`OpenCvSharp.Mat`](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/7b686c13-aaa7-5f3a-e2be-7da57895443f.htm) offers the [`Set<T>`](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/240a6bc7-420e-c112-39b6-a938bf3d81d1.htm) methods for setting/modifying individual matrix elements.

However, if you want/need to still keep working with pointer arithmetic, `OpenCvSharp.Mat` also offers [`Ptr`](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/ae2eb82c-668f-6f13-b343-14c2f3ab66e1.htm) methods that provide pointers to matrix elements or rows.